# C# and SQL Server 2005 connectivity

Tags: c#

I have a form in which I have a combobox that is populated with the column names of a table I have a textbox I intend to input values, when I click on the save button I want the data to be inserted into the various column that have been selected.

here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = AmiayaEjay-Vaio; Initial Catalog = RealTime; User ID = sa; Password = admin";

       String combo1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo3 = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo4 = comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo5 = comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo6 = comboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo7 = comboBox7.SelectedItem.ToString();
       String combo8 = comboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();

       query1.CommandText = "insert into dbo.DepthTable ( '" + combo1 + "','" + combo2 + "','" + combo3 + "','" + combo4 + "','" + combo5 + "','" + combo6 + "' ,'" + combo7 + "','" + combo8 + "') values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')";

       query1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       query1.Connection = myConnection;

       myConnection.Open();
       query1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }

   myConnection.Close();
}
```

I keep on getting error messages that I have invalid column names because the sql command can't see combo1-combo8 has a valid column name

Comment: Are you sure the text from the comboboxes have valid column names?  Maybe try wrapping the column names in square brackets in your query?

Comment: Please do some research on SQL injection attacks!

Comment: You don't need the single quotes in the column list, also create the string in a string variable to see what the value is, and validate this against your DB schema...

var query = "insert....."
query1.CommandText = query;

Comment: A **query** has just a single "r" - it's `query` - **not** `querry`

Comment: @Christiandev i think i tried your method and the result was still the same in the insertion command the sql isn't seeing the combo1- combo8 has a valid column name even after i had passed the values of the comboboxes

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see what you are actually calling. Run that in SQL Management Studio to identify the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM such as Entity Framework to give you a model for your database? You might find it makes your code a lot simpler and easier to handle (for starters, you won't have to mess around with creating SQL strings in your code). It will also remove the risk of SQL injection attacks (already mentioned by another commenter).

Comment: @RichardEv i haven't used ORM and don't know how to go about it..

Comment: @AmiayaEJay if you're interested, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Comment: @marc_s, sorry, was the 'querry' remark my typo?

AmiayaEJay, you took the output of that variable I mentioned, pasted that into SSMS, and validated the query?

Comment: @christiandev: no - sorry - I commented on the original post by Amiaya EJay - he consistently used "querry" with two "r"

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "'" signs in the comboX.

```
"insert into dbo.DepthTable (" + combo1 + "," + combo2 + "," + combo3 + "," + combo4 + "," + combo5 + "," + combo6 + "," + combo7 + "," + combo8 + ") values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')";
```

Comment: i tried doing it this way but the query isn't seeing the values of combo1 to combo8 as column names so the insertion is failing

Comment: How do you know that? maybe the column names are incorrect. Try to debug and extract the query text and run it in sql server management studio. Is there an error?

Comment: @Amiran i can't query the Script on sql server cos its a window form and i already inputed the combobox and textbox on it i tried using the try and catch exception to debug

Comment: Why you can't debug a windows form? What kind of data server do you use? Do you know how to activate profiling?

Comment: am using SQL server 2005 and don't know if it would be possible to query seen the data didn't process

Comment: Can't you debug and see the value of query1.CommandText or at least write the value to a log?